# How do I avoid for loop repetition for action on the same file?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Python noob in the house (yet):

I am handling a file line by line like:

```
import os

with open ('data.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        os.system("/bin/chmod -x {}".format(line))
        os.system("/usr/bin/clipass {}".format(line))
```

The main problem is that chmod can fail if the file was not found, and then, for  me,the remaining second command is waste of time.

What is the best practice to divide the action in two (besides repeating the loop twice). So I could run chmod on the given list and then make the second iteration to perform the shell script command.

Comment: Could you explain why you need chmod here ? whats the context?

Comment: can't you test the return value of the first `os.system` call?

Comment: also better use `os.chmod`

Comment: Does the first `chmod` command raise an exception if it fails? If so catch the exception and move on to the next file in the loop.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre chmod as only example here, there is more commands that would be needed to be performed separately on the same list, but I would like to devide them somehow, and the only thing that occured to me was writing the loop for every command I would need to perform

Comment: You are definitively right that multiple for-loops should be avoided. In this specific case I suggest you test if data.txt exists before you enter the loop in the first place. Also what is pretty common in Python is to `try` and `except`. If an error is raised in the first line of the loop, then Python will not execute the next one but rather jump right into the `except` section.

Answer (score 1):

Preamble:

- note that `os.system` is deprecated and has security issues, specially in your context (what if one of the lines has `"somefile; rm -rf /*"` ?) . You should use `subprocess.call`
- passing items from a file line-by-line requires you to `rstrip` or the linefeed is in the command and it will fail 100% of the time...

Now, you could use `continue` to skip the current item if return code of the command isn't 0 (except for the last command, where it doesn't matter):

```
with open ('data.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if subprocess.call(["/bin/chmod","-x",line.rstrip()])
           continue
        subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/clipass",line.rstrip()])
```